# How to write a general height-altering javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

You can write something like

```
function changeHeight() {
    document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = "200px"
}
<button type="button" onClick="changeHeight();"> Click Me!</button>
```

But if you would have a second div with the same id and a button it would still alter the height of the first element when pressing the second button. Is it possible to write a more general method that you can apply on all elements?

Comment: But if you would have a second div with the **same id** and a button. How?

Answer (score 2):

First, IDs are supposed to be unique. **Never have multiple elements with the same ID**.

If you need to change many different elements, pass arguments to your function:

```
function changeHeight(selector, height) {
    let element = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (element) {
        element.style.height = height;
    }
}

changeHeight('#chartdiv', '200px');
changeHeight('#otherElement', '500px');
```

Answer (score 0):

id is expected to be unique as it is the unique identifier for an element.
You can have multiple elements with same class name though.
In that case, you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class_name")[0].style.height = "200px";
```

document.getElementsByClassName("class_name") gives you an array of all elements with that class name in cronological order i.e. to access element with first occurance of that class you have to use 0th element as so on.

**Note : never reuse an id.**